# Can I make this function more efficient (Project Euler Number 9)?

Tags: java, algorithm

I just finished Project Euler problem 9 (warning **spoilers**):

```
A Pythagorean triplet is a set of three natural numbers, a < b < c, for which,
a^2 + b^2 = c^2

For example, 3^2 + 4^2 = 9 + 16 = 25 = 5^2.

There exists exactly one Pythagorean triplet for which a + b + c = 1000.
Find the product abc.
```

Here's my solution:

```
public static int specPyth(int num)
{
    for (int a = 1; a < num; a++)
        for (int b = 2; b < a; b++)
            {
                if (a*a +b*b == (num-a-b)*(num-a-b))
                    return a*b*(num-a-b); //ans = 31875000 
            }

    return -1;
}
```

I can't help but think that there's a solution that involves only one loop.  Anyone have ideas? I'd prefer answers using only one loop, but anything that's more efficient than what I currently have would be nice.

Comment: `32 + 42 = 9 + 16 = 25 = 52` - I don't understand this - You probably mean `3^2 + 4^2 = 9 + 16 = 25 = 5^2`

Comment: 3^2 + 4^2 = 9 + 16 = 25 = 5^2

Comment: If you want instant speedup, use `x*x` instead of `pow(x,2)`. Also, looking for a square root by exhaustive search is clearly something to improve on.

Comment: Can you confirm it IS a+ b+ c = 1000 ?

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik, I edited my code, thanks.  Nonetheless, it seems that due to something in trig or some mathematical principles, I feel like there should be a way to get this to work using only one for loop.

Comment: @Fabinout, not sure what you mean.  By construction, a+b+c must equal 1000: `(num-a-b)`, where num is 1000.

Comment: Only `c`-loop is needed.  You can find `a` and `b` by solving quadratic equation.

Comment: @SteveP. Indeed, I thought you mistook the problem, and actually looked for a² + b² =1000 but that was stupid. Sorry for the stupid comment ;)

Comment: Your second loop I think it has an error, how could `b = 2` and yet be smaller than a on the starting point? I think it kicks in from `a`'s second iteration. Check my answer.

Comment: @SteveP. Oh, and thanks for the Project Euler website. Seems awesome. Have a good day!

Comment: @Fabinout, no problem, you too.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_triple

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
if a + b +c = 1000
```

then

```
 a + b + sqroot(a² + b²) = 1000

 -> (a² + b²) = (1000 - a - b)²

 -> a² + b² = 1000000 - 2000*(a+b) + a² + 2*a*b + b²

 -> 0 = 1000000 - 2000*(a+b) + 2*a*b

 -> ... (easy basic maths)

 -> a = (500000 - 1000*b) / (1000 - b)
```

Then you try every b until you find one that makes a natural number out of a.

```
public static int specPyth(int num)
    {
        double a;
        for (int b = 1; b < num/2; b++)
        {
            a=(num*num/2 - num*b)/(num - b);

            if (a%1 == 0)
                return (int) (a*b*(num-a-b));
        }   

        return -1;
    }
```

EDIT: b can't be higher than 499, because c>b and (b+c) would then be higher than 1000.

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly what I was looking for.  Thanks! Thanks to everyone else, too.

Comment: Your function does not return the correct answer 60 when you call it with num = 12 = 3+4+5

Comment: @jwpat7 I got it: when you use a= 3 b=4 c=5, you use num = 12, and not num = 1000. you have then: a = (num*num/2 -num*4)/(num-4); -> a = (12*6 -12*4)/(12-4) = 3

Comment: Right; and replace 499 with num/2.  For example, 499 won't work in some cases with num > 1000

Comment: this is not working condition should be a^2+b^2==c^2 :-);

Comment: a b and c being positive integers,  it's the same as c = sqroot(a² + b²)

Answer (score 5):

I highly recommend reading http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_triple#Generating_a_triple and writing a function that will generate the Pythagorean triples one by one.

Not to give too much of a spoiler, but there are a number of other PE problems that this function will come in handy for.

(I don't consider this giving away too much, because part of the purpose of PE is to encourage people to learn about things like this.)

Answer (score 1):

First, since a is the smallest, you need not to count it up to num, num/3 is sufficient, and even num/(2+sqrt(2)).
Second, having a and constraints

```
a+b+c=num
a^2+b^2=c^2
```

we can solve this equations and find b and c for given a, which already satisfy this equations and there is no need to check if a^2+b^2=c^2 as you do now. All you need is to check if b and c are integer. And this is done in one loop

```
for (int a = 1; a < num/3; a++)
```

Comment: Thank you, that makes a lot of sense, but I don't understand why num/3 is sufficient.  Could you please elaborate?

Comment: @Steve I was wrong, actually n/2, because a,b,c form rectangular triangle.

Comment: No I was right, and we can check only cases when a < num/(2+sqrt(2)) because we can assume that a is the smallest side of the triangle.

Comment: Shouldn't it be a < num/(3+sqrt(3))?

Comment: maximal a which is sensibly to check is when the rectangular triangle is isoscales, then num=a+a+sqrt(2)*a.

Comment: I see my misunderstanding.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Runs in 62 milli seconds

```
    import time
    s = time.time()
    tag,n=True,1000
    for a in xrange (1,n/2):
        if tag==False:
            break
        for b in xrange (1,n/2):
            if a*a + b*b - (n-a-b)*(n-a-b) ==0:
                print a,b,n-a-b
                print a*b*(n-a-b)
                tag=False
    print time.time() - s
```

Answer (score 1):

C solution

Warning : solution assumes that GCD(a, b) = 1. It works here but may not always work. I'll fix the solution in some time.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void)
{
  int n = 1000;         // a + b + c = n
  n /= 2;

  for(int r = (int) sqrt(n / 2); r <= (int) sqrt(n); r++)
  {
    if(n % r == 0)
    {
      int s = (n / r) - r;
      printf("%d %d %d\n", r*r - s*s, 2*r*s, r*r + s*s);
      printf("Product is %d\n", (2*r*s) * (r*r - s*s) * (r*r + s*s));
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Solution uses [Euclid's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_triple#Proof_of_Euclid.27s_formula) for triplets which states that any primitive triple is of form a = r^2 - s^2, b = 2rs, c = r^2 + s^2.

Certain restrictions like sqrt(n / 2) <= r <= sqrt(n) can be added based on the fact that s is positive and r > s.

Warning: you may need long long if the product is large

Answer (score 0):

You say `a < b < c`, then `b` must always be bigger than `a`, so your starting point in the second loop could be `b = a + 1`; that would lead certainly to fewer iterations.

```
int specPyth(int num)
{
    for (int a = 1; a < num/3; a++)
        for (int b = a + 1; b < num/2; b++)
        {
            int c = num - a - b;
            if (a * a + b * b == c * c)
                return a * b * c; //ans = 31875000 
        }

    return -1;
}
```

Comment: Why num/3, then num/2?  How did you determine those bounds?

Comment: Because, if a> num/3 ,  then a+b+c> num.

Comment: That's true iff your statement is true.  You didn't explain why.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely not the most optimal solution, but my first instinct was to use a modified 3SUM. In Python,

```
def problem_9(max_value = 1000):
    i = 0
    range_of_values = [n for n in range(1, max_value + 1)]
    while i < max_value - 3:
        j = i + 1
        k = max_value - 1
        while j < k:
            a = range_of_values[i]
            b = range_of_values[j]
            c = range_of_values[k]
            if ((a + b + c) == 1000) and (a*a + b*b == c*c):
                return a*b*c
            elif (a + b + c) < 1000:
                j += 1
            else:
                k -= 1
        i += 1
    return -1
```

Answer (score 0):

In the first given equation, you have three variables `a, b, c`. If you want to find-out matching values for this equation, you have to run 3 dimension loop. Fortunately there is another equation `a+b+c=N` where `N` is known number.

Using this, you can reduce down the dimension to two because if you know two among the three, you can calculate the rest. For instance, if you know `a` and `b`, `c` equals `N - a - b`.

What if you can reduce one more dimension of the loop? It is possible if you fiddle with the two given equations. Get a pen and paper. Once you get the additional equation with two variables and one constant (N), you will be able to acquire the result in `O(n)`. Solve the two equations `a+b+c=n; a^2+b^2=c^2` taking `n` and `a` to be constant and solve for `b` and `c`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int t = in.nextInt();
    for(int a0 = 0; a0 < t; a0++){
        int n = in.nextInt(); 
        int max=-1;
        int multi=0;
       int b=1,c=1;
        for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)
            {
            if(2*(i-n)!=0)
            b=(2*i*n-(n*n))/(2*(i-n));
            c=n-b-i;
            if( (i*i+b*b==c*c)&& i+b+c==n && b>0 && c>=0 && i+b>c && c+i>b && b+c>i)
                {
                multi=i*b*c;
                if(max<multi)
                    max=multi;

            }
        }
        if(max==-1)
        System.out.println(-1);
        else
            System.out.println(max);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Python:

Before jump into the code, do a small exercise in algebra.

a^2 + b^2 = c ^2

a + b + c = 1000  -->  c = 1000 - (a+b)

a^2 + b^2 = (1000 - (a+b))^2

a = 1000*(500-b)/(1000-b)

Now the time to write the code.

```
for b in range(2, 500):
    a = 1000*(500 - b)/(1000 - b)
    if a.is_integer():
        c = 1000 - (a+b)
        print(a, b, c, a*b*c)
        break
```